# Does CP multiplier roll when evolving affect the max potential of the Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

So for some evolution there are variance in the multiplier when it goes onto the next evolution.

For example, a Pokémon has a 1.2 to 1.6 CP multiplier. When evolving, will getting a 1.2 multiplier put me at a permanent disadvantage against someone who had the exact same Pokémon and same level as me, but rolled a 1.6?

I know there is a disadvantage but could I make up for this by powering up the Pokémon itself or will my pokemon always be weaker than theirs because of a lower roll on the evolution?

Basically, does the evolution CP rolling affect the max potential of the Pokémon?

EDIT: I have heard in the last couple of days that IVs is what affects max CP, so a 95% IV will supposedly have a higher max CP than that pokemon with 70% IV. I don't know if this is confirmed but I will just put out the information I've found since others are also curious about this

Comment: The evolution multiplier is always the same for each Pokémon of the same type. A Caterpie will always have a multiplier of 1.1. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I was under the impression the multiplier isn't set for a lot of pokemons, I'm using pogotoolkit.com to calculate it, it shows caterpie for example has a multiplier of 1.04-1.08

Answer (score 2):

Evolving a Pokemon will not affect potential CP. CP is determined by a pokemons *Individual Values* or IVs.

In game, you are able to get a rough estimate of the IVs of a Pokemon by having your team leader appraise them. In order to be able to have your Pokemon appraised, you need to be at least level 5 and have joined a team.

To find your exact IVs, however, you'll have to go outside of the game and use an online calculator. I personally use the IV Rater here: 
[Silph Road](https://thesilphroad.com/research)

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering about this too.
http://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-list
shows detailed datamined information about the pokemon, maximum CP and minimum CP values for each pokemon.

So what you now need to do is make a colomn with X values of pokemon with the same level based on their dust costs:
((CP pre evolved pokemon)-(CP min pre evolved pokemon))/((CP min pre evolved pokemon)-(CP max pokemon))
make a colomn with corresponding Y values:
((CP evolved pokemon)-(CP min evolved pokemon))/((CP min evolved pokemon)-(CP max evolved pokemon))
find a correlation between the points.

If the is a correlation than the CP roll is passed on after evolving, if there is no correlation than the evolution gets a new CP roll.

If you already know that evolving rerolls please let me know, and also, if so, then this affects the maximum potential of the pokemon

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you will always be at a disadvantage. Leveling up your Pokemon before you evolve will not affect the max CP that's allowed in the next evolution. For example, you have a 50CP Pikachu who's CP bar is 50% of the way, which means you can level Pikachu up to 100CP. Your multiplier is about 2.5, so when you evolve, your Raichu's CP is going to be at 125CP. However, it is a well known fact that your CP percentage will be the same after evolution, so your Raichu's max CP is 250CP. Notice how even if you had leveled up your Pikachu to it's max of 100 before you evolved, you will basically have a maxed out Raichu at 250CP. This means that only the multiplier plays a role in how strong your next evolution becomes, not how much you level up that Pokemon before you evolve.